# How to use ActionSequence or LegacyActionSequence or similar to chain the action in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When i am performing this example, i am getting error I tried both ActionSequence and LegacyActionSequence. I need to find appropriate way to chain actions. I have looked into 
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/actions_exports_LegacyActionSequence.html

and other reference in StackOverflow those don't work as well.

I was trying this:

```
var assert = require('assert');
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
  By = webdriver.By,
  until = webdriver.until;

var chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

var options = new chrome.Options();
options.addArguments('start-maximized');
options.addArguments('disable-popup-blocking');
options.addArguments('test-type');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(options).build();

driver.get('http://www.softpost.org/selenium-test-page/');
var e3 = driver.findElement(By.tagName('select'));

//You can use ActionSequence class to perform actions in selenium

new webdriver.LegacyActionSequence(driver)
  .keyDown(webdriver.Key.SHIFT)
  .click(e3)
  //dragAndDrop(element3, element4).
  .keyUp(webdriver.Key.SHIFT)
  .perform();

And got following error:
new webdriver.LegacyActionSequence(driver)
^

TypeError: webdriver.LegacyActionSequence is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (ActionSequenceTest.js:19:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:719:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:228:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:575:3)
```

Comment: Have you looked here? https://www.softpost.org/selenium-with-node-js/performing-advanced-actions-using-selenium-in-node-js/

Comment: @Bill Hileman That is the exact example copied in the question up, that did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LegacyActionSequence` class is depricated (see source code [comment](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/bfe567d77a391628442449e0acfa76679e65d047/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/actions.js#L81) ), so use `actions()` instead.

```
driver.actions({bridge: true}).sendKeys(webdriver.Key.SHIFT)
        .click(e3)
        .sendKeys(webdriver.Key.SHIFT)
        .perform();
```

Comment: Thank you, I did start using actions after little bit of research, bridge mode is still required in case of chrome while for firefox it works without bridge.